# Given a secret - how does one generate a reproducible private key from it?

Tags: public-key

Let's say I have a secret "hitheremynameisbob"... I'd like to use this to encrypt/sign things. Is this possible or is it always expected to generate random secrets?

Comment: Short answer: It's always possible, you can just hash it with a secure hash function. But it's not usually a good idea because an attacker can make billions of attempts to guess your key and something that short and that non-random would not resist such an attack well.

Comment: I think you might be able to use a key derivation function (KDF).

Comment: Keep in mind that your key will not have more bits of security as the entropy of your input secret. In your example, the entropy is far less then 100 while, let's say  an AES key, should have security strength 128.

Comment: Most important note: you can create a public / private key **pair**. However, you need to establish *trust* in the public key. Obviously you cannot just substitute the secret for the public key. So after generating a key pair deterministically you will have to securely distribute your public key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generating private keys from passphrases / passwords is possible.<sup>1</sup>

**However, I strongly advise against basing your public key *exclusively* on your password and not proper (pseudo)randomness.**

If you publish your public key, everybody will be able to brute-force your password which will allow for passive decryption (encryption keys), identity theft (signature keys) or impersonation (signature keys / password re-use).

So let's get into the technicalities.

- What ever the methods say here. *Always* pre-process the password with the strongest password-based key deriviation function you can find (eg Argon2, you may have to turn the salt off for this).
- If your preferred library has a plug-in architecture for the RNGs, you can just replace the RNG with a contruction which is deterministic in your password input. AES-CTR would be a good example here.
- If not, your best bet is to restrict yourself to discrete-logarithm-based cryptography where the private key *literally* is just an integer, which you can get trivially from the transformed password. From there you use static group parameters and generate the public key on-the-fly as usual.

<sup>1</sup>: Bitmessage for example allows you to do that